# Error when trying printing *.prn file

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, process

I have problem with printing `*.prn` file. This is code:

```
Process process1 = new Process();
process1.StartInfo.FileName = "copy";
process1.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@" /b C:/test/test.prn \\127.0.0.1\{0}",
                                                         SelectPrinterForm.selectedLine);
process1.Start();
```

in `SelectPrinterForm.selectedLine` I have name of choosen printer. I've got error on `Start()` method with information **cannot find file**.

Edit (added stack trace):

```
w System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
w System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

### Questions:

Any suggestion why I've got this error?
 Also why when I use "@" I still have `"\\\\"` instead of `"\\"` ?

### Solution with help [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) and his answer above

```
Process process1 = new Process();
string computerFullName = Program.GetFQDN();
process1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process1.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@" /c copy /B C:\test\test.prn \\{0}\{1}",
                                                     computerFullName,
                                                     SelectPrinterForm.selectedLine);
process1.Start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any suggestion why I've got this error?

"copy" is not an executable file in Windows, it is a command for the *command interpreter*, cmd.exe.  The equivalent would be Filename = "cmd.exe", Arguments = "/c copy " + string.Format(...).  You probably won't be pleased with the command window or the lousy error reporting that produces, consider File.Copy() instead.

> Also why when I use "@" I still have "\\" instead of "\" ?

That's a debugger artifact, it does not know whether or not you used @ in your code so errs on the safe side and displays the string as a regular C# string literal.  Use the text visualizer to see the string as-is, click the spyglass icon.

Comment: Actually I can't even success call this command in cmd. But it is problem for another question.

Comment: You really help me.I put code with solution as edit of my post and check your answer as correct. Thanks